# How do I store image in SQL Server database using Classic ASP.?

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-server-2000, record, recordset

I'm uploading a image file, for that I have used `<input type="file" name="browse_file"  accept="image/*"/>` in my form.

I have a table called `covers` which has a column called `img` with data type `image`.
This is what my html looks like

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%"><b>Choose Cover:</b></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="browse_file"  accept="image/*"/>
                        <%
                            session("file_name") = request.Form("browse_file")
                        %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Cover Name:</strong></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cover_name" value=""></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Choose Category:</strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="disp_cat" onchange="return refresh_cat();">
                            <option selected="selected" value="0">Choose Category...</option>                           
                            <%
                                sql = "SELECT * from categories"
                                rs.open sql, con, 1, 2
                                do while not rs.eof
                            %>
                            <% if rs("name") = request.Form("disp_cat") then%>
                            <option value="<%=rs("name")%>" selected="selected"><%=rs("name")%></option>
                            <%else%>
                            <option value="<%=rs("name")%>"><%=rs("name")%></option>
                            <%end if
                                rs.movenext
                                loop
                                rs.close
                            %>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save_cover" onclick="return show_alert2();"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="cancel" onclick="return go_back();"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    if request.Form("save_cover") <> "" then
                    sql = "SELECT * from covers"
                    rs.open sql, con, 1, 2
                    rs.addnew

                    rs("c_name") = request.Form("cover_name")
                    rs("category") = request.Form("disp_cat")
                    rs("img") = request.Form("browse_file")
                    rs("date_upl") = date()

                    rs.update

                    response.Write("<script language='javascript'>{update1();}</script>")

                    rs.close
                    end if
                %>
                </table>
```

Connection to database is defined in a separate file called `database.asp`. The connection is working because all the columns like `c_name`, `category`, `date_upl` are getting updated in the database table `covers` except for the `img` column.

It's not taking up the image path. Is `rs("img") = request.Form("browse_file")` a wrong asp recordset to update database column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the SQL `Image` Datataype, that's a `binary field` to store the image itself, not the path - if you just want to store the path you would use a `varchar` data type.

If you want to store the image in the database (as binary) then the easiest way to do it is to save the file to disk (using [FreeASPUpload](http://www.freeaspupload.net/) etc), then tell SQL to load that file into the binary column, for example:

```
INSERT INTO covers(img)  
    SELECT * FROM   
    OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\uplaods\img0001.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS import
```

Or, if you want to insert the form data then upload the image into SQL afterwards:

```
UPDATE covers SET [img] = (SELECT NewImage.* from Openrowset(Bulk 'c:\uplaods\img0001.jpg', Single_Blob) NewImage) where Id = 10
```

Personally though - i dont store images in SQL, i keep them on disk and just store the filename in SQL, eg:

```
function SaveFiles
    Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey

    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)
    If Err.Number <> 0 then Exit function
    SaveFiles = ""
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    if (UBound(ks) <> -1) then
        SaveFiles = "<B>The following was uploaded:</B> "
        for each fileKey in Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
            SaveFiles = SaveFiles & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName & " (" & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).Length & "B) "

            Dim cover_name, disp_cat
            cover_name = Upload.Form("cover_name")
            disp_cat = Upload.Form("disp_cat")

            '#### Double Up any quotes (very lazy - use paramaterised SQL instead)
            cover_name = replace(cover_name, "'", "''")
            disp_cat = replace(disp_cat, "'", "''")

            'Dump file information into database
            SQLnewFile = "INSERT into covers (File_Filename, cover_name, disp_cat) " & _
                         "VALUES ('" & replace(Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName,"'","''") & "', '" & cover_name & "', '" & disp_cat & "')"              
            db.Execute(SQLnewFile)
        next
    else
        SaveFiles = "The file name specified in the upload form does not correspond to a valid file in the system."
    end if
end function
```

**Edit 1: In Response To Your Comments**

I dont usually write peoples code for them but you seem to be struggling to grasp the basics here, no, you would not edit your .inc file. The bit of code you would edit is the code where you check for the post and insert the data, for example:

```
if request.Form("save_cover") <> "" then
    Dim Upload, fileName, ks, fileKey, uploadsDirVar
    uploadsDirVar = "c:\Uploads\"

    Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
    Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)
    ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
    if (UBound(ks) <> -1) then
        for each fileKey in Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
            Dim cover_name, disp_cat
            cover_name  = replace(Upload.Form("cover_name"), "'", "''")
            disp_cat    = replace(Upload.Form("disp_cat"), "'", "''")

            SqlNewCover = "INSERT into covers (cover_name, disp_cat, FileName, img) " & _
                         "VALUES ('" & cover_name & "', '" & disp_cat & "', '" & replace(Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName,"'","''") & "', (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( Bulk '" & uploadsDirVar & replace(Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName,"'","''") & "', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB))"              
            db.Execute(SQLnewFile)
        next
    end if
end if
```

Comment: is BLOB present in Sql server 2000..Because I'm using sql Server 2000. I tried using **image**,**nvarchar**,**binary** but no luck so far.

Comment: Yes, all those blob based data types exist in SQL 2000 - but that isnt your problem? Your question states that you're trying to store the image path in the database - not the image itself? My asp example shows how to save the image to disk and store the filename in SQL - i.e. to a varchar column.

Comment: I can save the image path in my database, I wanted to save an image now in the databsase. Is there a way of doing it using classic asp and SQL SERVER 2000..??..

Comment: Yes, using the OpenRowSet(Bulk, 'Path', Single_Blob) examples in my answer - but you still need to save the image to disk first, and note that the path used is from the SQL Servers perspective.

Comment: I already have a connection file separately stored and calling it in every file using `<!--#include file="database.asp"-->` do I need to edit this file...or the select statement which I mentioned in my question...??

Comment: See Edit 1 on my answer, ive done a quick example as to where you would put the code.

Comment: i get this error must a file is missing in this case kindly check. this is my error... `Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01FA)
Class not defined: 'FreeASPUpload' `

Comment: Again, i linked that in my answer: http://www.freeaspupload.net/ - download the `freeASPUpload.asp` file and include in your script: `<!--#include file="freeASPUpload.asp"-->`

Comment: thanks for all your help. when I gave the external link for that **freeASpUpload.asp** file and when clicked on Save button. Browser keeps on loading...showing waiting for **localhost**...and nothing happens after that...at last I get a message server timeout session. I check what the issue is thank you once again. Really appreciate your effort.